# Unexpected output using `observeEvent`, `updateTabsetPanel` and nested modules

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

My app has several screens and I deal with it using `tabsetPanel()`, hiding the tab headers (I
leave them visible here for debugging) and selecting them using `updateTabsetPanel()`

It starts on a home screen (coded into `mod_home_ui()` / `mod_home_server()`)
You push a button to trigger an action, there would be several but I just left one here, called "learn" (coded into `mod_learn_ui()` / `mod_learn_server()`)

The "learn" module itself contains games, here I left only two games and used the same module functions for both for simplicity.
A reactive value `panel_flag`, determines which game should be played, here I force it to `FALSE`, which means game2 should be played.

This last step doesn't work as I expect, while messages show that the code went through the right `updateTabsetPanel()` call, the expected tab isn't selected, and moreover, the expected text isn't shown on top of the screen.

This looks like a namespacing issue but I don't understand what I did wrong here.

The code below can be copy pasted in one go to run the app and here's a gif of what would happen :

[image]

```
# main ui and server

app_ui <- function() {
  tagList(
    fluidPage(
      title = "My app",
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "switcher",
        #type = "hidden",
        selected = "home",
        tabPanel("home",  mod_home_ui("home_ui")),
        tabPanel("learn", mod_learn_ui("learn_ui"))
      )
    )
  )
}

app_server <- function(input, output,session) {
  learn <- callModule(mod_home_server, "home_ui")
  observeEvent(learn(), {
    message("In app_server: observeEvent on learn() to switch to 'learn' panel")
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "switcher", selected = "learn")
  })
  callModule(mod_learn_server, "home_ui", learn = learn)
}
```

```
# home module

mod_home_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textOutput(ns("some_text")),
    actionButton(ns("learn"), "learn")
  )
}

mod_home_server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$some_text <- renderText("I expect clicking on the above to trigger game2, not game1")
  ns <- session$ns
  reactive({
    res <- req(input$learn)
    message(
      'In mod_home_server: returning req(input$learn) in mod_home_server to trigger learn()')
    res
  })
}
```

```
# learn module

mod_learn_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabsetPanel(
    id = ns("switcher"),
    #type = "hidden",
    tabPanel("game1", mod_game_ui(ns("game1_ui"))),
    tabPanel("game2", mod_game_ui(ns("game2_ui")))
  )
}

mod_learn_server <- function(input, output, session, learn){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  panel_flag <- eventReactive(learn(), {
    message('In mod_learn_server: eventReactive on learn() to trigger relevant game')
    # in reality this would be computed or random
    FALSE
  })
  
  observeEvent(panel_flag(), {
    message('In mod_learn_server: observeEvent on panel_flag()')
    if (panel_flag()) {
      message('In mod_learn_server:  select "game1" panel')
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "switcher", selected = "game1")
    } else {
      message('In mod_learn_server: select "game2" panel')
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "switcher", selected = "game2")
    }
  })  
  callModule(mod_game_server, "game1_ui")
  callModule(mod_game_server, "game2_ui")
}
```

```
# game module

mod_game_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textOutput(ns("some_text")),
    "I expect another line of text above this one"
  )
}

mod_game_server <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  output$some_text <- renderText("I expect this to be shown")
}
```

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(app_ui, app_server)
```

Comment: Wrong module's ID for mod_learn_server in app_server?

Comment: Thanks @Victorp! YBS answered as well below. Do you have any tips on how to avoid or debug these issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callModule(mod_learn_server, "learn_ui", learn = learn)`

instead of

`callModule(mod_learn_server, "home_ui", learn = learn)`

should fix it.

Comment: That was it! Victor commented it too. I've spent considerable time narrowing a bigger app to this reprex and still didn't catch it after rereading this code a 1000 times, though I had a feeling it'd be as silly as it proved to be. Do you know of any trick or approach to avoid these issues or solve them fast ? I feel that I could do this mistake over and over again and in bigger apps it will always take time to solve.

Comment: I am not that good in modules set-up.  That is the reason I have not converted my large shiny app to modules.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure this doesn't happen again I made a package that tests the consistency of the shiny code, it is designed with the {golem} framework and conventions in mind.

Install with `remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/shinycheck")`

This is what I get when I run `shinycheck::check_shiny()` on my real app (which is slightly different from the above):

```
shinycheck::check_shiny()
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Check that all module scripts contain exactly 2 functions named appropriately
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Check that all module ui functions use ns() or NS() on argument named id/inputId/outputId
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Check that in ui, module ui functions, named `mod_MODULE_ui` refer to modules which exist and ids fed to them are prefixed with "MODULE_"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Check that ns() and NS() are never called in an argument that isn't id/inputId/outputId
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Check that the module args of callModule are of the form "mod_MODULENAME_server", that there is an R file properly named for "MODULENAME", and that the id argument is prefixed by "MODULENAME_"
* In 'mod_main_server', a call to `callModule` has a module argument `mod_learn_server` and an `id` argument 'home_ui' that is not prefixed by the module name 'learn'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Check that modules and module ids mentionned on both ui and server side are consistent
* In 'mod_main_ui' we find the module id 'learn_ui' but we don't find it in 'mod_main_server'
```

We find  :

> In 'mod_main_server', a call to `callModule` has a module argument `mod_learn_server` and an `id` argument 'home_ui' that is not prefixed by the module name 'learn'

> In 'mod_main_ui' we find the module id 'learn_ui' but we don't find it in 'mod_main_server'

This would have made debugging trivial.

See more at https://github.com/moodymudskipper/shinycheck